# Windows XP batch command schtasks doesnt' run a remote script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a `batch` file in order to run automatic scripts on several remote PCs.
My main machine should be able to connect to any remote PCs and set a local scheduled task.
The batch file uses these commands:

```
schtasks /delete               <--- remove any previous version
         /S \\10.1.2.3         <--- the remote PC's IP
         /U theAdministrator   <--- the username to access the PC
         /P MyPassword         <--- the password to access the PC
         /TN MyTask            <--- task name
         /F                    <--- don't ask, just do it option

schtasks /create 
         /S \\10.1.2.3 
         /U theAdministrator 
         /P MyPassword 
         /RU theAdministrator  <--- the username to execute the task 
         /RP MyPassword        <--- the password to execute the task
         /SC dayly /MO 1       <--- run every day
         /TN MyTask 
         /TR C:\task.bat       <--- the script to run on the remote PC
```

When I launch the first `/delete` command everything works, but the second returns a warning:
*"task has been created but probably it will not run because it hasn't been possible to set the account information"* 
 (I'm sorry if this is not the exact error message but I have to translate it by myself)

I'm sure that username and password are correct because the `/delete` command is OK, and also `/create` one creates the task, even if it doesn't run.

Therefore the problem should be with `/RU` and `/RP` options...

---

**Solution:**

I wasn't able to execute the command itself without this error message, anyway I've reached my aim and found two different options:

***The simplest way using the AT command:***

```
AT \\10.1.2.3 12:00 C:\task.bat
```

It has no problem but needs to have specified an hour to run; this means if you want the task to be executed immediately you'll have to chatch `%time%` variable.
This option also doesn't allow to set an user to run the task (I've tested it as Administrator and the task was set to execute as `NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM`)

***The full featured way using PsTools:***
Passing the `schtasks /create` command to `PsExec`

```
set command=schtasks /create /SC dayly /MO 1 /TN MyTask /TR C:\task.bat /RU theAdministrator /RP MyPassword
PsExec \\10.1.2.3 -u theAdministrator -p MyPassword %command%
```

***NB.*** 
The target *IP*, *user* and *password* to access the remote PC have to be set within `PsExec` command, therefore you don't need them on `schtasks`.
 
The script task.bat already exists on root C:\ of the target PC.

Comment: as far as I know /RU and /RP   swithces cannot be used for remote execution of schtasks.You can only use /U and /P.

Comment: Unfortunately removig the two options I have the same warning, and I suppose with /RU and /RP it just ignores them. Anyway I have found this reference, in which the example reports a remote access with both /RU and /RP: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff356867.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are the PC's on a domain?? 
I've used schtasks on a domain before, and it works without the `/ru` and `/rp`.  I just used `/u` and `/p` as the username and password of the machine that I was scheduling the task on.
Never tried it on standard workgroup/homegroup machines though.

You may also want to look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/241825/schtasks-cant-administer-remote-tasks), and make sure UAC is off on all remote machines, as thes could cause issues later.

*Edit*

I've just tried from one laptop to another (no domain involved).
These two lines work (in CMD, so should work through batch) for me

```
schtasks /delete /S \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /U USERNAME /P PASSWORD /TN MyTask /F
schtasks /create /S \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /U USERNAME /P PASSWORD /TN MyTask /SC once /st START_TIME /it /TR c:\test.bat
```

Things to note are;
 - Obviously, replace the x's with the IP you need, and the USERNAME and PASSWORD with relevant data
 - I used `/sc once /st START_TIME`, and not your `/sc daily /mo 1`, but that shouldn't make a difference
 - I've added `/it` which (taken from CMD) "Enalbes the task to run interactively..." (in my experience, not using it has cause problems)
 - The user on the laptop I was scheduling the task for does not exist on the laptop I ran schtasks from
 - The user on the laptop I ran schtasks from does not exist on the laptop i was scheduling the task for (so users not existing on client/host does not matter)

Comment: I've tried your suggestions but unfortunately it seems not to be an UAC issue (I have also deactivated the firewall and enabled the file and printer sharing service as Microsoft suggest). /IT is not an allowed options in Windows XP (I should have specified it before). Anyway I have found a different way to reach my goal (added to the original question) thank you.